# source jupyter_notebook_config.py syntax error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When I run the jupyter_notebook_config.py file,

> > source jupyter_notebook_config.py

An error occurred as follows:

```
bash: ./jupyter_notebook_config.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: ./jupyter_notebook_config.py: line 3: `c = get_config()  #noqa'
```

I tried to remake the config file, and it was the same.
also I deleted () and try `c = get_config`, and it also does not work.

Comment: You can't run `source` on a python file. `source` is executing the script in your current shell, which is bash. Bash doesn't do python, if you look at the error message, you can see that bash is reporting the syntax error.